# Get user identity from Active Directory ACL

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I'm trying to get the account linked to a group which has the "send-to" extended right.

```
ActiveDirectorySecurity ads = myGroup.ObjectSecurity;
foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in ads.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(NTAccount)))
{
  if (ar.ObjectType.ToString() == "ab721a55-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b")
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ar.IdentityReference);
  }
}
```

Problem is IdentityReference holds "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" and not the account I'm searching.

How can I retrieve it ?

I know it should be doable since powershell can do it.

```
Get-ADPermission -identity myGroup | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send*") -an
d ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Format-List *
```

Comment: Does "Authenticated Users" actually have "Send To" rights?

Comment: Per se, no it's a local right.  If you execute the Powershell query, you have "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" as a User and the account as Identity.

Comment: If you look at the Security tab in AD Users and Computers, do you see that Authenticated Users has the "Sent to" right?

Comment: You may already be aware, but Exchange also keeps its own list of who can send email to a mailbox/DL in its `AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom` and `AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting back a list of rights, but this does not determine effective access/the actual access (in case there is a deny somewhere).  Just wanted to make sure you were aware of that.

According to MSDN, when retrieving your access rules, the target type must be an object that can be cast as a SecurityIdentifier object. (I recommend using it in case it can no longer be resolved, you will always be left with a SID as opposed to an error)

For more info: [DirectoryObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.getaccessrules%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I prefer using "Format-Table -AutoSize" instead of "| Format-List *".

```
Get-ADPermission -identity myGroup | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send*") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

And here's some helper code:

```
 //REFERENCES
 using System.DirectoryServices;
 using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
 using System.Security.Principal;
 using System.Security.AccessControl;
 //END OF REFERENCES

 //Exchange Shell Command:
 //Get-ADPermission -identity "<AD Distinguished Name>" | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send*") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")} | Format-Table -AutoSize

 string groupSAMAccountName = "YOUR_GROUP_NAME";
 GroupPrincipal pGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupSAMAccountName);
 DirectoryEntry deGroup = pGroup.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

 //Extended Rights Reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405676.aspx
 //Exchange right: allows sending mail as the mailbox.
 Guid exRight_SendAs = new Guid("{ab721a54-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b}"); //GUID has 54
 //Exchange right: allows sending to a mailbox.
 Guid exRight_SendTo = new Guid("{ab721a55-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b}"); //GUID has 55

 ActiveDirectorySecurity ads = deGroup.ObjectSecurity;
 AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = ads.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

 List<ActiveDirectoryAccessRule> exRight_SendTo_Rules = new List<ActiveDirectoryAccessRule>();

 foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in rules)
 {
    //Goal - get all entries that are classified as exRight_SendTo
    if(ar.ObjectType.Equals(exRight_SendTo))
    {
        exRight_SendTo_Rules.Add(ar);
    }
 }

 //This is where you would need to get all the sids of a account that it is a member of to filter down what rules apply to your account
  //You would probably want to include the Everyone SID and Authenticated Users SID as well.
  //From there you would bitwise operate each rule all over the place to determine if you actually have access granted on an account.
  //Just because an entry has ALLOW Send-As, doesn't mean that's your EFFECTIVE ACCESS... you don't know if another entry of another membership you belong to has DENY.
 foreach(ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in exRight_SendTo_Rules)
 {
    string friendlyName = "";
    try
    {
        friendlyName = ar.IdentityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
    }
    catch
    {
        friendlyName = "[Unable to resolve] SID " + ar.IdentityReference.Value;
    }

    string ar_Result = string.Format(@"Identity={0}, User={1}, Deny={2}, Inherited={3}", 
                pGroup.DistinguishedName,
                friendlyName, 
                (ar.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny).ToString(), 
                ar.IsInherited);

     Console.WriteLine(ar_Result);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ar_Result);
 }
```

Remember to upvote if helpful!

Edit:

"When working with an extended right ACE, you must assign the [ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the AccessMask."

Which is 0x100 ... which means its the ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight

```
ActiveDirectoryRights test = (ActiveDirectoryRights)0x100;
```

I do not know if the ace will be enforced if you do not give it the:

```
ar.ActiveDirectoryRights = ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight;
```

Therefore I do not know if you find any extended right aces without this value if you should ignore it as an entry or not.  I WOULD ASSUME IT SHOULD BE IGNORED IF IT DOES NOT HAVE ENUM FLAG OF EXTENDEDRIGHT.

Edit #2:  The correct way to logic this is to get all permissions of "EXTENDEDRIGHT" then compare ObjectType GUIDs, you must also include Empty GUID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} entries as they apply to ALL Extended Rights.... then you filter down which entries apply to a particular account matching all the sids that account belongs to, then you combine what applies and see if that account is ultimately allowed or denied.

Comment: I figured you wanted to know what the effective access of X Account was.  In this case, if X Account effective access was "[ALLOW] Send-To" to send an email to the myGroup email.